# What would you call a group that contained UX, training and documentation?

Tags: documentation, training, title

What would you call a group within an organization that contained UX responsibilities as well as training and documentation? Marketing and product groups already exist outside of this entity... trying to stay away from those disciples in the title.

Comment: Thoughts on "User-Centered Products Group," or "End User Products Group".

Comment: "Human Factors" also works.

Comment: I agree 100% @keshlam, I am a human factors psychologist by training. The issue I continually run into is that human factors comes off very technical, while UX or CX is more colloquially more inviting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be considered as falling into the realm of **Customer Experience**.

CX is not *limited* to these activities of course.

I see no harm in bringing UX and CX together, while training and documentation are methods of increasing customer engagement and improving the customer experience.

I also don't think a CX group needs to exist only in large orgs, although that is often the perception!

---

<sub>Ref: [Customer Experience](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_experience) on wikipedia</sub>

Comment: Problem already solved. Thanks for leading me to the UX vs. CX discussion.

Comment: What if some of the documentation and training that is being created is targeted at the servicing community of the product/solution? Wouldn't the term "Customer" be somewhat limited in that case?

Comment: @Montag451 'Customer' has some associated baggage. The 'servicing community' has its own needs. They are still customers or users in that sense - but just a *different set* of customers with a different set of needs compared to that of the 'end-customers' of the core product or service. It's critical that your servicing community's needs are considered because they are *absolutely* part of the end-user customer experience and have a key influence on their broader end-to-end experience. Create the training and docs for the servicing community within the context of the bigger picture.

Answer (score 1):

I lead a team of one doing exactly this, and my title is ... User experience!

My vision is the following: to grow the real UX component so that our products and services require as little documentation and training as possible.

Note: this wasn't the title I chose but how it was created. Some organizations have less flexibility in how titles are created. The title is not the role, in the same way as the map is not the territory.

Comment: What if some of the documentation and training that is being created is targeted at the servicing community of the product/solution? Wouldn't the term "User" be somewhat limited in that case?